# Is there a gender-neutral prefix for "parent"?

Tags: prefixes, grammatical-gender, gender-neutral

The prefixes "patr-" and "matr-" refer, respectively, to father and mother--e.g., a patriarch is a father who rules a family, and a matrilineal society is one where property is passed from mother to daughter.

Is there a prefix that refers more generally to "parent"?

Comment: There is the word **ancestors**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It's certainly a good suggestion, but not so specific to parents.

Comment: @DavidM I know. It's also not really a prefix.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I was on the same fence with *progenitor*.  *Ancestr-* can be used as a prefix of sorts.  *Ancestry, Ancestral, etc.*  Yes, it's mostly carrying the suffix, but still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, and that prefix is parent.

From [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parent);

> Origin of PARENT
>
> Middle English, from Anglo-French, from Latin parent-, parens; akin to Latin parere to give birth to

Comment: It should end with a vowel to function as a standard English prefix comparable with "patri-" and "matri-", right?  Otherwise how can I attach it to suffixes like "-archy", "-cracy", "-philia", "-mancy", etc.?  That makes me more inclined to go with Roger's "parri-", but there aren't any examples other than "parricide", so a pattern isn't established.

Comment: @sigil English is a very irregular language. **Con** is a prefix that ends in a consonant. So there are precedents.

Comment: Hmm..."parri-" looks more technical and attaches nicely to the usual bag of Greek suffixes, but there's more evidence in the corpus for "parent-" (e.g. "parentage").  The only samples of "parriarchy" online are misspellings of "patriarchy", whereas usages of the neologism "parentarchy" appear to have the correct usage.  I'll go with this one.

Comment: I'm disappointed that a Google for 'parentomancy' returns 0 hits! That seems like a word that deserves wider use.
OTOH, parentophobia and parentophilia return 40K and 100K hits respectively.

Comment: @Spike0xff It's up to six now! Of course they're all to your comment.

Answer (score 6):

"Parr-" seems to be the general term to refer to either parent, at least insofar as the term "parricide" vs. "matricide" or "patricide".

[Parricide: Characteristics of sons and daughters who kill their parents](http://www.currentpsychiatry.com/index.php?id=22661&tx_ttnews%5btt_news%5d=175452)

[Understanding Parricide: When Sons and Daughters Kill Parents](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&ved=0CGsQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbooks.google.com%2Fbooks%2Fabout%2FUnderstanding_Parricide.html%3Fid%3D9QIWaI3Od4QC&ei=V5APU8ztHKSV1AGt74GQBg&usg=AFQjCNH0Rdl_i5g4O-D_j06-aPePeDz2MQ&sig2=nR5WDogoq4-JMav3-sbrVQ)

I haven't done an exhaustive search to see if this prefix is used in any other contexts, though.

Comment: I went with Elliott Frisch's answer, based on empirical evidence (see my comment on that answer), but "parri-" feels more prefix-y.  If you can find other examples to support the claim, I'd be willing to reconsider your answer.