# What's in-between matriarchal and patriarchal?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word that describes a society or family-system where power / responsibility is shared equally among males and females?

Specifically I was wondering if it might end with -riarchal.

For example, "As an egalitarian, I don't believe in a matriarchal OR patriarchal system, but rather (blank)."

Comment: The anthropologists have a word for it I'm sure.

Comment: Yes, @Mitch, I believe it is known as Greatriarchal, and such states are known to conflict with states which adhere to its polar-opposite policy, Hateriarchal.

Comment: *Bitriarchal*...

Comment: *Greatriarch* means Me-maw is the boss, which in many families is certainly the case.

Comment: Lessee -- midway between **m**atriarchal and **p**atriarchal  is "no" -- **no**atriarchal.

Comment: On the (uneducated) assumption that the words _matriarchal_ and _patriarchal_ are composed of roots meaning essentially "maternally-based hierarchy" and "paternally-based hierarchy," respectively, a case could be made for an egalitarian society being _flat_.

Comment: ["A few people consider any non-patriarchal system to be matriarchal, thus including __genderally equalitarian__ systems, but most academics exclude them from matriarchies strictly defined."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriarchy). Since 'equalitarian' is a malapropism of 'egalitarian' I would not take that phrasing for 'neither patri- or matriarchal' as standard.

Comment: Since the literature seems to confirm that even though there may be matriarchal societies, none are exclusively matriarchal (whereas the great majority are exclusively patriarchal (which is independent from matri- or patrilineal)). So I think 'egalitarian' or 'non-headed' or 'non-gender-preference leadership' will work.

Comment: Must be "*atriarchal*" or in programming circles perhaps "*[mp]atriarchal*".

Comment: By the way, it's "matri-arch-al" and "patri-arch-al, not "mat-riarch-al" and "pat-riarch-al".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The combining form *parri-* is the gender independent equivalent to *matri-* and *patri-*, as in the word *parricide*.[¹](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154505/is-there-a-gender-neutral-prefix-for-parent) So you could use the term ***parriarchy*** if you want a strict parallel with *patriarchy* and *matriarchy*.

One difficulty is that *parriarchy* is not in wide circulation. *Parriarch* is found in the English corpus by Google search, but most hits seem to be the result of text recognition errors (“rr” for “tr”).

Also, *parriarchy*’s neutral position between *patriarchy* and *matriarchy* is a bit weak, etymologically speaking. According to *[Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=patriarch)* and *[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/matriarch)*, the word *patriarch* comes from the Greek *patria* (clan), not the Latin *pater* (father). By contrast, the eighteenth century coining *matriarch* does come from the Latin *mater* (mother), and the prefix *parri-* probably is a cognate of the Latin *parus* (relative). This is not to deny that *patriarchy* implies a male ruler; *patria* is related to *pater* (father).

Ultimately there is no simple answer, because the correct term actually depends on who does hold the power. For example, the term ***egalitarian*** is often used of a society that is not patriarchal or matriarchal but is characterized by decentralized power, the term ***gerontocracy*** is used when power is in the hands of elders but independent of their gender, and so on.